# Is there a way to gain XP from smelting in Electric Furnaces?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-industrialcraft

In my modded 1.7.10 world, when I smelt stuff in my Electric Furnace(s) I don't gain XP Orbs as I would if I smelted from my regular Furnace(s), which I could have then used to get Unbreaking and Fortune enchantments to further boost productivity.

So I am wondering if there is some for me to gain XP for smelting stuff in my Electric Furnace(s)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to gain XP from smelting with Electric Furnaces, you can only gain XP from smelting in regular Furnaces. This is similar to if you were to use a hopper to take the completed product out of a regular furnace, you would also get no XP.